# namespace load failed for ‘sf’ (R package) , unable to load shared object

Tags: r, linux

I am attempting to install R 'sf' on a Centos machine. After extended problems with gdal (now fixed by building from source),  I now get:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
```

unable to load shared object '/home/my_user_name/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-
    library/3.4/sf/libs/sf.so':
    /home/my_user_name/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/sf/libs/sf.so: 
    undefined symbol: *ZN15OGRMultiSurface18CastToMultiPolygonEPS*

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

So, this problem was apparently caused by my manual install of gdal not correctly linking to geos.

So I just reinstalled gdal following these instructions (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix) with --with-geos=yes as a flag to ./configure.

This solved the problem.