# Installing RQGIS

Tags: r, postgresql, qgis

I am trying to install `RQGIS` library for R and used the [documentation](https://github.com/jannes-m/RQGIS) by the creator of the library.

I ran the package install. But when I checked using `library(RQGIS)`, the library was not present.

I went to `/tmp/Rtmp7Gejy7/downloaded_packages` to extract the library and moved it to `/home/../R/x..linux-gnu-library/3.2/`.

I get the following error on the console:

> Loading required package: RQGIS Failed with error:  ‘‘RQGIS’ is not a
>   valid installed package’

Can someone help me solve this issue? I am facing the same issue with RPostgreSQL.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to solve RPostgreSQL issue but not the RQGIS. I installed the library from terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rpostgresql
```

Then, it needed another library: `DBI`

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-dbi
```

It's now working on R Studio.

Comment: Do you get any error message when installing the package with install.packages("RQGIS")?

Comment: No error. Just a warning:
`Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RQGIS’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: A non-zero exit status means the package was not correctly installed. Where there any other warnings or errors during the installation?

Comment: Sorry about that. There was this error:
`ERROR: dependencies ‘rgdal’, ‘sf’ are not available for package ‘RQGIS’
* removing ‘/home/sarvagya/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RQGIS’`

Comment: And were there any messages when installing sf and rgdal? My guess would be missing external libraries.

Comment: how do I install these dependencies?

Comment: That depends which dependency is reported as missing and which OS you are using. Google will be your friend ...

Comment: Thanks. Although, what would you suggest for the dependencies mentioned on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I cannot make any suggestion if you do not post the error messages you are getting when trying to install `sf` and `rgdal`.

Comment: I was able to install "sf" and "rgdal" by installing R 3.3. Now, just this error:




`configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/home/sarvagya/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/sf’`

Comment: So you were *not* able to install `sf`. Updated `GDAL` for Xenial can be found here: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis

Comment: So, I tried to install GDAL and manually installed it. I got the following error for installing `sf`: `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):`, which means that GDAL is manually installed. I tried `pip` and `easy_install`.

I also tried this [link] [1], where I got `GNUmakefile:82: recipe for target 'gdalinfo' failed`


  
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184326/namespace-load-failed-for-sf-r-package-unable-to-load-shared-object?rq=1